# monodevelop shortcuts and auto-code

Tags: eclipse, monodevelop

i'm using MonoDevelop after used Eclipse for several years.

In eclipse when i create a class, eclipse auto-generates all stub methods from extended class or implemented interface.

How i can obtain same job in monodevelop?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the context menu on the base class/interface name in the class declaration.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can press `Alt+Insert` to bring up a code generation quick-menu with the option of implementing interface methods (among other features).

Note that you need to have the character cursor in the body of the class, that implements the interface that you want to create stub methods from.